# Capturing WPF Runtime BindingExpression errors

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, binding

We can all see Runtime `BindingExpression` errors in the Visual Studio Output Window. But can we capture these events in the running app itself? I'm hearing about WPF tracing... does this have something to do with this facility? Also, the `System.Windows.Data` namespace contains no documented events (like a `BindingExpression` error event), why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is "not really."

[There was a blog post from 2009 that went more into the details of debugging this situation, but it no longer exists and so the link has been removed from this answer.]

Comment: Looks like the link is dead again. You may want to consider moving the relevant information from the blog to your answer (if you can find / remember it).

Comment: Sorry. It appears that Bea Stollnitz has moved on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that is not exactly true. Yes the binding logic is dynamic, and its in its own pipeline that is hard to follow. BUT, I found this great blog entry from Jason Bock.

http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/Default.aspx?blog=entry.0f221e047de740ee90722b248933a28d

TL;DR: Jason has a class that can provide the method of capturing any binding errors as an event.